# Why do the values inside the PriorityQueue change after the poll method in java?

Tags: java, collections, priority-queue

This is the code and the output is below it why do the value **"5" and "6"** i mean how are the new priorities set after poll method in a PriorityQueue (similarly the other elements in the queue) . I am preparing for java certification exam and i always tend to choose the wrong answer due to this concept, any help is welcomed.

```
import java.util.*;

public class PriorityQueueDemo {
public static void main(String args[]) {
  // create priority queue
  PriorityQueue < Integer >  prq = new PriorityQueue < Integer > (); 

  // insert values in the queue
  for ( int i = 3; i  <  10; i++ ){  
     prq.add (new Integer (i)) ; 
  }

  System.out.println ( "Initial priority queue values are: "+ prq);

  // get the head from the queue
  Integer head = prq.poll();

  System.out.println ( "Head of the queue is: "+ head);

  System.out.println ( "Priority queue values after poll: "+ prq);
 }
}
```

Output :

```
Initial priority queue values are: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Head of the queue is: 3
Priority queue values after poll: [4, 6, 5, 9, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the other possible answers. The order of elements printed is not specified. But you can draw conclusions based on the number of elements and the values that are shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values haven't changed, they are just printed in a different order.
The [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()) for `PriorityQueue` returns the elements in the order they are returned by its `Iterator`. If you read the Javadoc for [`PriorityQueue#iterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator()) you see the following:

> *Returns an iterator over the elements in this queue. The iterator does not return the elements in any particular order.*

So, you can't draw any conclusions from your printouts, since no effort is being made by the `PriorityQueue` to print them in any particular order, by priority or otherwise.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Per [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#poll()), `poll()`

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.

If you want to [peek at the head](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#peek()) without removing it, call `peek()`

> Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.

**Order:** A priority queue achieves high performance [O(log(n)) time for the enqueing and dequeing, constant time for the retrieval] by not sorting all of its elements. It only does a partial sort to get the least element to the head position. So when the inherited `AbstractCollection#toString()` method iterates through the elements, only the first one is in sorted order. When you remove the head element, some more sorting happens and the other elements change relative positions.

See Wikipedia for how [priority queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) work.

Answer (score 2):

For exam remember that PriorityQueue always make the first entry in correct order and rest of the entries can be in any order because

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to
>   traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.

This trick saved my time to answer some trick question on exam

Comment: +1. But is it specified anywhere that toString() prints even the first entry in the correct order? The Javadoc only seems to say "not guaranteed in any particular order". If so, how can they ask this in an exam? (Of course, depending on the other answer choices, there may be other clues).