# Member function in java priority queue returning but not removing the specified value?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I was wondering in Java priority queue, is there a member function that returns the specified value (either min or max depending on the structure of priority queue) without removing it?

`remove()` removes this element.

The below example illustrates my question.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    PriorityQueue<Integer> que = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
    que.offer(3);
    que.offer(1);
    que.offer(2);
    System.out.println(que.remove());
    System.out.println(que.remove());
    System.out.println(que.remove());
    //Instead of removing them directly, I would 
    //like to see whether the min numbers are greater than, say 2. 
    //If so, remove them in increment order.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `peek` method you can check the value of the element at the head of the queue without removing it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#peek()

Comment: Thank you. It works, although I read the documentation and it suggest "the head of this queue", without the word "specified". I thought it would return 3 in my example.

Comment: @JiajuShen: the documentation for the priority queue says: "The head of this queue is the least element with respect to the specified ordering.". So the lowest value should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

**peek()**

> Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue, or returns
>   null if this queue is empty.

Please refer here for more detailed explaination: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927009/why-do-the-values-inside-the-priorityqueue-change-after-the-poll-method-in-java)